# Ejecutar un archivo .py desde otro archivo

Tags: python

Tengo un script que como resultado genera un archivo excel con los valores que deseo, script por nombre: ejemplo.py, este archivo necesito que se ejecute cada 60[s], para lo cual quiero emplear otro archivo con el siguiente código:

```
import time

def ejecutar_Script():  

    python ejemplo.py
    print('Ejecutando Script...')
    # Contador en segundos que manda a dormir la máquina
    time.sleep(60)

while True:

    ejecutar_Script()
```

hasta el momento no me ha funcionado.

Comment: ¿Quieres que se ejecute y que una vez terminada la ejecución  espere 60 segundos para volverlo a ejecutar? ¿O quieres que lo ejecute cada 60 segundos sin importar cuanto tarde (o si la ejecución anterior terminó)? Ten en cuenta que no es lo mismo y si el script tardará más de 60 segundos en terminar, en el segundo caso podemos tener condiciones de carrera y resultados inesperados (por ejemplo si modifica archivos)

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar la librería os de Python. Por ejemplo:

```
import os
os.system('python ejemplo.py')
```

Espero que sea de ayuda

Comment: ok pero si el archivo a ejecutar no está en el directorio y está en otro, como puedes cambiar de ruta?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes utilizar esta función:

exec(open("Nombre archivo Python.py").read())

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).